# express.js - best POST json schema validator

Tags: javascript, json, validation, express, schema

I'm searching for a module to validate POST json requests in my **Express.js** application.

What json schema module do you use in your node.js apps?

I assume node-validator (https://github.com/chriso/node-validator) is not an option here because it works only with strings.

Comment: I recommend you look into this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/great-json-validator. It’s super easy to implement, and quite light weight, if you’re concerned about it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I made this - if you are still interested: https://npmjs.org/package/isvalid

Comment: Try http://indicative.adonisjs.com/ , has human friendly api to validate schema

Answer (score 16):

I recently wrote [express-jsonschema](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-jsonschema). The main differences with the other validators out there are:

1. You use the standard [json schemas](http://json-schema.org/) for validation.  If you have
   written other server side languages you probably have used them
   before.
2. It doesn't control how your application responds to invalid
   data. It does give you an opportunity to hook in and respond however
   you want.  In my experience this is something that is nice to
   control.

[express-schema-validator](https://npmjs.org/package/express-schema-validator), [express-validate](https://npmjs.org/package/express-validate), and
[Paperwork](https://www.npmjs.com/package/paperwork) are all great. They each have their own unique syntax for declaring schemas and also control how your app responds to invalid data (i.e. status code and data structure).

Comment: Up-vote for the rational behind the design of the solution: (1) using [json-schema](http://json-schema.org), a dedicated schema language that will help in standardizing how we design our API, and for (2) avoiding to hijack the control from the application (separation of concerns).

Comment: Same here. Upvote for inversion of control :D. IMO this is the best solution.

Answer (score 4):

I made [Paperwork](https://npmjs.org/package/paperwork), which is a very simple solution for JSON validation. You can do things like:

```
app.post('/my/route', paperwork({
  username: /[a-z0-9]+/,
  password: String,
  age: Number,
  interests: [String],
  jobs: [{
    company: String,
    role: String
  },
}, function (req, res) {
  // ...
});
```

It will validate:

```
{
  username: 'brucewayne',
  password: 'iambatman',
  age: 36,
  interests: ['Climbing', 'CQC', 'Cosplay'],
  jobs: [{
    company: 'Wayne Inc.',
    role: 'CEO'
  }]
}
```

Or will silently responds a 400 error with information about what's wrong. Check the doc to do  more advanced usages.

Comment: thanks, it looks very nice!

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of options for those who choose JSON Schema validation rules. Good libs comparison here: https://github.com/ebdrup/json-schema-benchmark